# Inheritance in Java array: why is this a type mismatch?

Tags: android, arrays, inheritance, android-fragments

I have a `BaseFragment` so called LeaderboardFragment that extends `Fragment`:

```
public class LeaderboardFragment extends Fragment
```

And when I define the next in the `FragmentActivity`, I get type mismatch:

```
Fragment[] fragments = new LeaderboardFragment[] {new Fragment1(),
    new Fragment2(), new Fragment3()};
```

And these fragments all extend `LeaderboardFragment`. Something like this should be possible right, because they simply inherit that super class.

***EDIT***
This is how my FragmentActivity looks like:

```
public class LeaderboardTabHost extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager myViewPager;
Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[] {new Fragment1(), new Fragment2(), new Fragment3()};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_collection_object);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    myViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        return fragments[index];
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Fragment1 extends LeaderboardFragment {

    public Fragment1() {
        super();
        setTag("time");
    }
}

public class Fragment2 extends LeaderboardFragment {

    public Fragment2() {
        super();
        setTag("distance");
    }
}

public class Fragment3 extends LeaderboardFragment {

    public Fragment3() {
        super();
        setTag("speed");
    }
}
```

}

And the exact error is:

```
//Type mismatch: Cannot convert from LeaderboardTabhost.Fragment1 to Fragment
```

Comment: Show the definitions for `FragmentX` *and* show the *exact* error message (multiline indents and all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I have accidentally extended `android.app.Fragment` while I was aiming for `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

I fixed the imports and the errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that works. Theoretically, if you define fragments as `Fragment[]` and initialize it with `LeaderboardFragment[]`, what should happen you add other types of `Fragment` which are not `LeaderboardFragment` to that array?

Anyway, I don't see why you can't use this:

```
Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[] {new Fragment1(),
new Fragment2(), new Fragment3()};
```

In the end, the objects in the array are instances of classes that extend `Fragment` class.

Comment: Defining the array like that also causes a Type mismatch.

Comment: The classes `Fragment1`, `Fragment2`, `Fragment3` extend `Fragment`, right?

Comment: No, as I stated above, they extend a 'baseclass' called `LeaderboardFragment` that extends `Fragment`.

Comment: That means that they extend `Fragment` as well. They are `nephews`, not `children`, but they inherit `Fragment`. Anyway, that is strange. I am not sure why it throws that exception.